# MongoDB query that joins multiple collections, groups, sorts push array and restructures the result

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pipeline

MongoDB Playground link [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XjDJiNYhUhk). `Data` and `Desired Result` are listed below. Students can take the same course again and again. I would like the result to match the student with `_id: 1` and then group by course and then sort by semester startDate and only return the most recent semester. Is this possible?

**DATA**

```
db={
  registers: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      student: 1,
      school: 1,
      course: 1,
      semester: 1,
      grade: 59
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      student: 1,
      school: 1,
      course: 1,
      semester: 2,
      grade: 99
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      student: 1,
      school: 2,
      course: 2,
      semester: 3,
      grade: 100
    }
  ],
  students: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: "Student1"
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Student2"
    }
  ],
  schools: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: "Zefram Cochrane High School"
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Star Fleet Academy"
    }
  ],
  courses: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: "Warp Theory"
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Temporal Mechanics"
    }
  ],
  semesters: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: "Fall 2320",
      startDate: ISODate("2320-02-01"),
      endDate: ISODate("2320-05-31")
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Fall 2320",
      startDate: ISODate("2320-09-01"),
      endDate: ISODate("2320-12-31")
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: "Spring 2321",
      startDate: ISODate("2321-02-01"),
      endDate: ISODate("2321-05-31")
    }
  ]
}
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
[
  {
    "course": {
      "name": "Warp Theory"
    },
    "grade": 99,
    "school": {
      "name": "Zefram Cochrane High School"
    },
    "semester": {
      "endDate": ISODate("2320-12-31T00:00:00Z"),
      "name": "Fall 2320",
      "startDate": ISODate("2320-09-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    "student": {
      "name": "Student1"
    }
  },
  {
    "course": {
      "name": "Temporal Mechanics"
    },
    "grade": 100,
    "school": {
      "name": "Star Fleet Academy"
    },
    "semester": {
      "endDate": ISODate("2321-05-31T00:00:00Z"),
      "name": "Spring 2321",
      "startDate": ISODate("2321-02-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    "student": {
      "name": "Student1"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes. I would like the query to always use the semester with the largest start date, per course. If there's only one semester for the course than use that one. Then, unwind the semester property. Finally, I would like to move the nested properties under _id (created during $group), up one layer so they are no longer nested. Is this possible?

Comment: Is that ok? let me know

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to [coffee me](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/minsky) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give just an overview of the changes:

- Filter the max startDate
- Included grades
- tried to improved slightly the format you request.
  (can be rolled back)

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "course": "Warp Theory",
    "grade": 99,
    "school": "Zefram Cochrane High School",
    "semester": {
      "endDate": ISODate("2320-12-31T00:00:00Z"),
      "startDate": ISODate("2320-09-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    "student": "Student1"
  },
  {
    "course": "Temporal Mechanics",
    "grade": 100,
    "school": "Star Fleet Academy",
    "semester": {
      "endDate": ISODate("2321-05-31T00:00:00Z"),
      "startDate": ISODate("2321-02-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    "student": "Student1"
  }
]
```

**Pipeline**

```
db.registers.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      student: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "students",
      localField: "student",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "student"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$student"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "schools",
      localField: "school",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "school"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$school"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "courses",
      localField: "course",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "course"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$course"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "semesters",
      localField: "semester",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "semester"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$semester"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "semester.grade": "$grade"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        course: "$course.name",
        school: "$school.name",
        student: "$student.name"
      },
      semester: {
        $push: "$semester"
      },
      max: {
        $max: "$semester.startDate"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      course: "$_id.course",
      school: "$_id.school",
      student: "$_id.student",
      semester: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$semester",
          as: "s",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$s.startDate",
              "$max"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "grade": "$semester.grade"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "max",
      "_id",
      "semester._id",
      "semester.grade",
      "semester.name"
    ]
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$semester"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$grade"
  }
])
```